# What is the easiest way to implement simple notifications to an android app, triggered from a django app?

Tags: android, django, push-notification, pusher

I'm working on my first Django app that already uses Pusher's service for some parts in my site - it works great.

I would like to add a notification app for Android, which will alert a registered user about a new activity regarding to that specific user.

I would like to know:

1) What is the best way to implement that? Should I use Pusher for this as well or should I use Google's push services (or maybe another service?)? What will be the easiest?

2) How will the Android app user get authenticated to Django? How will the app 'know' if the user is logged in using the device's browser at the same time and no notifications should be sent?

I'm new to Android. If someone could answer / describe the general architecture / lead to a proper documentation it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) - https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/.

For 3rd-party, there's Urban Airship - http://urbanairship.com/.

If you use C2DM, you'll get a token specific to a user. You use that token to send a message to the user.

You need to figure out if the user is online (browsing) so you won't need to send notification. You can check out this app: https://bitbucket.org/zalew/django-online-status/wiki/Home.

Comment: Thanks. Aren't Pusher and Urban Airship very much alike? As for C2DM: that token that you're talking about, on what is it based?